# Python/Django и API vk.com - проблема загрузки фото

Tags: python, post, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, django

Задача: загрузить фотографии с сайта в альбом пользователя vk.com

view.py

```
path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(current_supply.photo))
f_handler = open(path, 'rb')
r = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file1': f_handler})
return r.text
```

Для проверки использовал php на своем хостинге, файл приходит, но вконтакте возвращает следующий json:

```
{"server":402630,"photos_list":"[]","aid":146590454,"hash":"0d123277e8b30a03413dd65e067b634c"}
```

Что я могу делать не так?
[Документация](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5&f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B2+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: покажите содержание files['file1']

Comment: $_FILES в PHP:

Array ( [file1] => Array ( [name] => 2_19.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /home/users2/z/username/tmp/phpVYLzE5 [error] => 0 [size] => 0 ) )

Под Django, вероятно, не получится ничего увидеть.

Comment: "[size] => 0" натолкнул на мысли, которые помогли решить проблему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**

С помощью модуля poster

```py
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

""" get server url """
url = u'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getUploadServer?aid=%s&gid=%s&access_token=%s' % (aid, GROUP_ID, TOKEN)
result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = simplejson.loads(result.read())
upload_url = content['response']['upload_url']

""" send file """
register_openers()
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file1": open('/home/dir/path/to/file.jpg', "rb")})
request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, datagen, headers)
content = simplejson.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
```

Файлы загружаются, параметры фото отдаются. Далее их нужно вернуть серверу с помощью photos.save API VK